# Remove decimal (.0000) opencart 1.5.6

Tags: opencart, currency, opencart-module

Hello how I can get ride off decimal on opencart 1.5.6 completly for admin and fronted ?

if my price 5000 then display as it no need add 5000.0000.
I'm try to change from database product price set from 15.4 to 15.0 but its say invalid default value date added.
also already change library/currency but no luck. im out of option to solve this one.
and code for currency is like this

```
return $string;
```

change to this

```
return rtrim($string, '.00');
```

Answer (score 0):

solve just export to below mysql version and change 15.4 to 15.0 or use notepad or any editor change manually